# Why is my game just not starting? I just added a list and 2 more loops but now it just wont start up

Tags: python, pygame

I have a snake game but what's different is enemies spawn every time the snake eats a block. I've looked over the code and the game just won't display, does anyone know why? Any help is appreciated.

```
import sys,pygame
import random

 
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake Game')
screen_width, screen_height = 500,400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

fps = pygame.time.Clock()
 
snake_speed = 20
 
black = pygame.Color(0, 0, 0)
white = pygame.Color(255, 255, 255)
red = pygame.Color(255, 0, 0)
green = pygame.Color(0, 255, 0)
blue = pygame.Color(255, 0, 0)

pygame.init()

snake_position = [100, 50]
 

snake_body = [  [150, 80],
                [100, 50],
                [100, 50],
                [80, 50]
            ]

food_position = [random.randrange(1, (screen_width//10)) * 10,
                  random.randrange(1, (screen_height//10)) * 10]
food_spawn = True

enemy_position = [random.randrange(1, (screen_width//10)) * 10,
                  random.randrange(1, (screen_height//10)) * 10]

enemy_spawn = True
```

This was the first thing I added. (The list)

```
enemy_list = [random.randrange(1, (screen_width//10)) * 10,
              random.randrange(1, (screen_height//10)) * 10]

direction = 'RIGHT'


score = 0
 

def show_score(choice, color, font, size):
   
    
    score_font = pygame.font.SysFont(font, size)
     
    
    score_surface = score_font.render('Score : ' + str(score), True, color)
     
    
    score_rect = score_surface.get_rect()
     
    
    screen.blit(score_surface, score_rect)
blue = pygame.Color(0, 0, 255)

def game_over():
            
    my_font = pygame.font.SysFont('comic sans', 50)
    
    game_over_surface = my_font.render('Your Score is : ' + str(score), True, red)
    
    game_over_rect = game_over_surface.get_rect()
    
    game_over_rect.midtop = (screen_width/2, screen_height/4)
    
    screen.blit(game_over_surface, game_over_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            
while True:
    change_to = direction
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                change_to = 'UP'
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                change_to = 'DOWN'
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                change_to = 'LEFT'
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                change_to = 'RIGHT'
    
   
    if change_to == 'UP' and direction != 'DOWN':
        direction = 'UP'
    if change_to == 'DOWN' and direction != 'UP':
        direction = 'DOWN'
    if change_to == 'LEFT' and direction != 'RIGHT':
        direction = 'LEFT'
    if change_to == 'RIGHT' and direction != 'LEFT':
        direction = 'RIGHT'

    if direction == 'UP':
        snake_position[1] -= 10
    if direction == 'DOWN':
        snake_position[1] += 10
    if direction == 'LEFT':
        snake_position[0] -= 10
    if direction == 'RIGHT':
        snake_position[0] += 10
```

Then I added this loop and inserted the list

```
while True:
    for enemy_position in enemy_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, pygame.Rect(
            enemy_position[0], enemy_position[1], 10, 10))

    for enemy_position in enemy_list:
        if snake_position[0] == enemy_position[0] and snake_position[1] == enemy_position[1]:
            game_over()
```

Then my another loop I put in. (and the list)

```
while True:
    
    snake_body.insert(0, list(snake_position))
    if snake_position[0] == food_position[0] and snake_position[1] == food_position[1]:
        score += 1
        food_spawn = False

        enemy_list.append(
            [random.randrange(1, (screen_width//10)) * 10,
             random.randrange(1, (screen_height//10)) * 10]
        )

    else:
        snake_body.pop()


         
    if not food_spawn:
        food_position = [random.randrange(1, (screen_width//10)) * 10,
                          random.randrange(1, (screen_height//10)) * 10]

        food_spawn = True
    screen.fill(black)
    
    for pos in snake_body:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, pygame.Rect(
          pos[0], pos[1], 10, 10))
    
         
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, pygame.Rect(
      food_position[0], food_position[1], 10, 10))
           
        
    if snake_position[0] < 0 or snake_position[0] > screen_width-10:
        game_over()
        
    if snake_position[1] < 0 or snake_position[1] > screen_height-10:
        game_over()
    
    
    for block in snake_body[1:]:
        if snake_position[0] == block[0] and snake_position[1] == block[1]:
            game_over()

    
    show_score(1, white, 'comic sans', 20)
    show_score(1, white, 'comic sans', 20)
    
    
    pygame.display.update()

    
    fps.tick(snake_speed)
```

Comment: Although they come in handy sometimes, I'm not a fan of `while True` loops. It is better to check a condition that clearly signals the end of the loop. Since you have two `while True` loops that don't have a `break`, it is unlikely that the second loop will ever be entered. But maybe I just misinterpret your code snippets.

Comment: @Idkmane Can you please change the title of game to something that [summarises your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have written three separate `while True` methods. The first to take in controls, the second to do state control, and the third for actually drawing the game.

However, if you want all of these to run at once, they must be inside the same loop. At the moment, your first `while True` loop is running over and over again. Thus, your second and third loops, which actually draw the game out, are never running.